# Надо синонимизировать [уведомления]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки

- [notifications](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications) (156 вопросов) - в описании написано "Уведомление - это ..."
- [уведомления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (36 вопросов) - описания нет

об одном и том же - их надо синонимизировать. Есть ещё [push-уведомления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (94 вопроса), но это, наверное, уже другое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 171 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 156 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 152 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'notifications': [notifications] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 188
tag remapping of [уведомления] and [notifications] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
9 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym notifications -> уведомления was approved!
```